# How to show full text for tweets in tweepy

Tags: python, text, tweepy

I'm trying to use the extended mode to show all the text of the tweet with tweepy, but at the end is not working and the tweets are cutted. Any help?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import tweepy
from tweepy import Cursor
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

query = "Apple"
language = "en"
tweet_mode = "extended"
results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, count=1500)

def on_status(self, status):
         print(status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
```

e.g of what happens:

```
10xX10Caro Berlin, Deutschland 2020-10-13 04:11:24 Tweeted: Me and Renée will responding to the owner of the place we rent in November. We are looking forward to Kalmar very m…
```

Comment: be more specific what's not working. [This is how I'm getting the entire tweet text.](https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot/blob/master/bot/utils/processor.py#L197) `self.status_tweet["extended_tweet"]` is not always populated hence why I have several `if elif` conditions checking for the text. Afterwards I convert the text a little e.g. to enable [markdown links](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the tweet's full text to a .csv file? Please check if the full text is written there.

Probably you are seeing part of the tweet only when you are viewing through;

```
print(status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
```

statement.

It happened to me when using Google Colaboratory once.